# unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.illegalargumentexception for zeebe broker

Tags: docker-compose, zeebe

2020-08-07 16:27:43.318 [] [main] INFO  io.zeebe.broker.StandaloneBroker - Starting StandaloneBroker v0.24.1 on MyComputer with PID 18304 (E:\zeebe-distribution-0.24.1.tar\zeebe-distribution-0.24.1\zeebe-broker-0.24.1\lib\zeebe-distribution-0.24.1.jar started by Syed Shafeeq Peeran in E:\zeebe-distribution-0.24.1.tar\zeebe-distribution-0.24.1\zeebe-broker-0.24.1)
2020-08-07 16:27:43.331 [] [main] INFO  io.zeebe.broker.StandaloneBroker - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-08-07 16:27:45.725 [] [main] WARN  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The location [C:\Users\SYEDSH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.11949349417879858240.9600] specified for the base directory is not a directory
2020-08-07 16:27:45.746 [] [main] INFO  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener -

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-08-07 16:27:45.749 [] [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The location [C:\Users\SYEDSH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.11949349417879858240.9600] specified for the base directory is not a directory
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at io.zeebe.broker.StandaloneBroker.main(StandaloneBroker.java:52) [zeebe-distribution-0.24.1.jar:0.24.1]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The location [C:\Users\SYEDSH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.11949349417879858240.9600] specified for the base directory is not a directory
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.initBaseDir(Tomcat.java:850) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.getServer(Tomcat.java:639) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.getService(Tomcat.java:571) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:182) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:178) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:158) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
... 9 more

Comment: Can someone please help me with the above mentioned problem?

Answer (score 0):

The exception message tells you that the given path is not a directory.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The location [C:\Users\SYEDSH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.11949349417879858240.9600] specified for the base directory is not a directory 2020-08-07 16:27:45.746
```